# Number theory used in cryptography

Tags: notation, terminology, cryptography

I am entering the realm of cryptography and encountering Number Theory related stuff a lot (As expected). I have a good knowledge and background on mathematics but I have been away for a while. So if anyone can give me a refresher (basic, not deep) about the below it would be perfect. (links to proper explanations are also a good idea)

1. B : {0, 1} <sup>d</sup>   --> {0, 1}<sup>d</sup>
2. A Є {0, 1}<sup>d</sup>
3. uniform distribution

Comment: What's that symbol next to $A$ in $2.$?

Comment: @Ahmed: I have a feeling it is meant to be $\in$.

Comment: @Regret true, it is BELONGS

Comment: Since you're working in cryptography 1) is B is a map from a d bit binary number to another d bit binary number and A is a d bit binary number.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche it's the same poster

Comment: 1. $B$ is a function that maps binary strings of length $d$ to binary strings of length $d$. 2. $A$ is a binary string of length $d$. 3. Search it on Google, and choose the Wikipedia link (which will most likely be at the top of the page).

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I posted that question too. But a moderator asked me to ask each category alone. So I asked another one here. However, It seems that I have a ban now for asking too many questions, although I was told to do so by a moderator. What has happened? I am truly disappointed.

Comment: It wasn't a moderator who gave you that suggestion, it was a regular user.  (Moderators have a diamond symbol after their name.)  You should have edited your original question to narrow the scope.  Anyway, you have accepted the answer at your previous question, so it seems you are satisfied with the answer you got.  There is thus no need for this question now because it was asked before and it got an accepted answer.

Comment: True. Because I wrote this one, then the answer of that one came. (Interstellar movie not gonna happen here). So I do not need this question here. Can you explain why I was banned? Also not that the title of this community says `For people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\{0,1\}$$ is the set that contains 0 and 1, which you should think of as the possible values of a bit. $$\{0,1\}^d$$ is the set of words made of exactly $d$ bits. For example,  $\{0,1\}^4$ includes the word `1011`.

$$b: \{0,1\}^d\to \{0,1\}^d$$ means that $b$ is a function that takes one of these words and yields a word.

$$A\in \{0,1\}^d$$ means that $A$ is oe of those words of $d$ bits.

A uniform distribution means that you select randomly from some set of things and each thing in the set is equally likely to be chosen.

Comment: thanks a lot guys for the answer and the edits :) much appreciated !